# Split pane gui object

Tags: user-interface, wolfram-mathematica

I've been developing a gui for some time, which requires the creation of common control objects that Mathematica lacks (e.g. spinner, treeview, openerbar, etc.). One is the multipanel, i.e. a pane object that is split into two (or more) subpanes, where the divider can be set by the mouse. Here is my version of a dual pane. I would like to hear your opinion and ideas about how to expand it to handle not just 2 but any number of subpanes, and also how to optimize it. At present, for heavily loaded subpanes, it lags terribly, no idea why.

```
Options[SplitPane] = {Direction -> "Vertical", 
   DividerWidth -> Automatic, Paneled -> {True, True}};
SplitPane[opts___?OptionQ] := 
  Module[{dummy}, SplitPane[Dynamic[dummy], opts]];
SplitPane[val_, opts___?OptionQ] := SplitPane[val, {"", ""}, opts];
SplitPane[val_, content_, opts___?OptionQ] := 
  SplitPane[val, content, {100, 50}, opts];
SplitPane[Dynamic[split_, arg___], {expr1_, expr2_}, {maxX_, maxY_}, 
   opts___?OptionQ] := 
  DynamicModule[{temp, dir, d, panel, coord, max, fix, val},
   {dir, d, panel} = {Direction, DividerWidth, Paneled} /. {opts} /. 
     Options[SplitPane];
   dir = dir /. {Bottom | Top | "Vertical" -> "Vertical", _ -> 
       "Horizontal"};
   d = d /. Automatic -> 2;
   split = If[NumberQ[split], split, max/2];
   val = Clip[split /. {_?NumberQ -> split, _ -> maxX/2}, {0, maxX}];
   {coord, max, fix} = 
    Switch[dir, "Vertical", {First, maxX, maxY}, 
     "Horizontal", {(max - Last[#]) &, maxY, maxX}];
   panel = (# /. {None | False -> 
          Identity, _ -> (Panel[#, ImageMargins -> 0, 
             FrameMargins -> -1] &)}) & /@ panel;

   Grid[If[dir === "Vertical",
     {{
       Dynamic[
        panel[[1]]@
         Pane[expr1, ImageSize -> {split - d, fix}, 
          ImageSizeAction -> "Scrollable", Scrollbars -> Automatic, 
          AppearanceElements -> None], TrackedSymbols :> {split}],
       Deploy@EventHandler[
         MouseAppearance[
          Pane[Null, ImageSize -> {d*2, fix}, ImageMargins -> -1, 
           FrameMargins -> -1], "FrameLRResize"],
         "MouseDown" :> (temp = 
            coord@MousePosition@"CellContentsAbsolute"; 
           split = 
            If[Abs[temp - split] <= d \[And] 0 <= temp <= max, temp, 
             split]), 
         "MouseDragged" :> (temp = 
            coord@MousePosition@"CellContentsAbsolute"; 
           split = If[0 <= temp <= max, temp, split])],
       Dynamic@
        panel[[2]]@
         Pane[expr2, ImageSizeAction -> "Scrollable", 
          Scrollbars -> Automatic, AppearanceElements -> None, 
          ImageSize -> {max - split - d, fix}]
       }},
     {
      List@
       Dynamic[panel[[1]]@
         Pane[expr1, ImageSize -> {fix, split - d}, 
          ImageSizeAction -> "Scrollable", Scrollbars -> Automatic, 
          AppearanceElements -> None], TrackedSymbols :> {split}],
      List@Deploy@EventHandler[
         MouseAppearance[
          Pane[Null, ImageSize -> {fix, d*2}, ImageMargins -> -1, 
           FrameMargins -> -1], "FrameTBResize"],
         "MouseDown" :> (temp = 
            coord@MousePosition@"CellContentsAbsolute"; 
           split = 
            If[Abs[temp - split] <= d \[And] 0 <= temp <= max, temp, 
             split]), 
         "MouseDragged" :> (temp = 
            coord@MousePosition@"CellContentsAbsolute"; 
           split = If[0 <= temp <= max, temp, split])],
      List@
       Dynamic[panel[[2]]@
         Pane[expr2, ImageSizeAction -> "Scrollable", 
          Scrollbars -> Automatic, 
          ImageSize -> {fix, max - split - d}, 
          AppearanceElements -> None], TrackedSymbols :> {split}]
      }
     ], Spacings -> {0, -.1}]
   ];
SplitPane[val_, arg___] /; NumberQ[val] := 
  Module[{x = val}, SplitPane[Dynamic[x], arg]];

pos = 300;
SplitPane[
 Dynamic[pos], {Manipulate[
   Plot[Sin[x (1 + a x)], {x, 0, 6}], {a, 0, 2}], 
  Factorial[123]}, {500, 300}]
```

[image: SplitPane output]

Comment: Quite impressive! As to optimization: how about using ControlActive and/or the SynchronousUpdating option?

Comment: Very nice work, but keep in mind that the format of your "question" is not a good fit for the site. The Mma community here is generally permissive about that, but try to formulate your questions according to the general rules of the site to avoid closing (and delete) votes.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The key to generalizing to several panels was to refactor your code. In its present form, while very nice, it was mixing visualization / UI primitives and options with the split logic, and had lots of duplicate code. This made generalization hard. Here is the refactored version:

```
ClearAll[SplitPane];
Options[SplitPane] = {
    Direction -> "Vertical", DividerWidth -> Automatic, Paneled -> True
};
SplitPane[opts___?OptionQ] :=   Module[{dummy}, SplitPane[Dynamic[dummy], opts]];
SplitPane[val_, opts___?OptionQ] := SplitPane[val, {"", ""}, opts];
SplitPane[val_, content_, opts___?OptionQ] :=
    SplitPane[val, content, {100, 50}, opts];
SplitPane[sp_List, {cont__}, {maxX_, maxY_}, opts___?OptionQ] /; 
        Length[sp] == Length[Hold[cont]] - 1 :=
  Module[{scrollablePane, dividerPane, onMouseDownCode, onMouseDraggedCode, dynPane,
      gridArg, split, divider, panel},
    With[{paneled = Paneled /. {opts} /. Options[SplitPane],len = Length[Hold[cont]]},
       Which[
          TrueQ[paneled ],
             panel = Table[True, {len}],
          MatchQ[paneled, {Repeated[(True | False), {len}]}],
             panel = paneled,
          True,
            Message[SplitPane::badopt]; Return[$Failed, Module]
       ]
    ];

    DynamicModule[{temp, dir, d, coord, max, fix, val},
      {dir, d} = {Direction, DividerWidth}/.{opts}/.Options[SplitPane];
      dir =  dir /. {
         Bottom | Top | "Vertical" -> "Vertical", _ -> "Horizontal"
      };
      d = d /. Automatic -> 2;
      val = Clip[sp /. {_?NumberQ -> sp, _ -> maxX/2}, {0, maxX}];
      {coord, max, fix} =
        Switch[dir,
          "Vertical",
             {First, maxX, maxY},
          "Horizontal",
             {(max - Last[#]) &, maxY, maxX}
        ];
      Do[split[i] = sp[[i]], {i, 1, Length[sp]}];
      split[Length[sp] + 1] = max - Total[sp] - 2*d*Length[sp];
      panel =
          (# /. {
            None | False -> Identity, 
            _ -> (Panel[#, ImageMargins -> 0,FrameMargins -> -1] &)
           }) & /@ panel;
      scrollablePane[args___] :=
          Pane[args, ImageSizeAction -> "Scrollable", 
               Scrollbars -> Automatic, AppearanceElements -> None];
      dividerPane[size : {_, _}] :=
          Pane[Null, ImageSize -> size, ImageMargins -> -1,FrameMargins -> -1];

      onMouseDownCode[n_] := 
        Module[{old},
          temp = coord@MousePosition@"CellContentsAbsolute";
          If[Abs[temp - split[n]] <= d \[And] 0 <= temp <= max,
            old = split[n];
            split[n] = temp-Sum[split[i], {i, n - 1}];
            split[n + 1] += old - split[n];       
        ]];

      onMouseDraggedCode[n_] :=
         Module[{old},
            temp = coord@MousePosition@"CellContentsAbsolute";
            If[0 <= temp <= max,
               old = split[n];
               split[n] = temp -Sum[split[i], {i, n - 1}];
               split[n + 1] += old - split[n];
            ] ;
         ];

      SetAttributes[dynPane, HoldFirst];
      dynPane[expr_, n_, size_] :=
          panel[[n]]@scrollablePane[expr, ImageSize -> size];

      divider[n_, sizediv_, resizeType_] :=
         Deploy@EventHandler[
            MouseAppearance[dividerPane[sizediv], resizeType],
           "MouseDown" :> onMouseDownCode[n],
           "MouseDragged" :> onMouseDraggedCode[n]
         ];

      SetAttributes[gridArg, HoldAll];
      gridArg[{content__}, sizediv_, resizeType_, sizeF_] :=
         Module[{myHold, len = Length[Hold[content]] },
           SetAttributes[myHold, HoldAll];
           List @@ Map[
             Dynamic,
             Apply[Hold, 
                MapThread[Compose,
                   {
                      Range[len] /. {
                        len :>               
                          Function[
                             exp, 
                             myHold[dynPane[exp, len, sizeF[len]]], 
                             HoldAll
                          ],
                        n_Integer :>
                          Function[exp,
                             myHold[dynPane[exp, n, sizeF[n]],
                                divider[n, sizediv, resizeType]
                             ], 
                          HoldAll]
                      },
                      Unevaluated /@ Unevaluated[{content}]
                    }] (* MapThread *)
               ] /. myHold[x__] :> x
           ] (* Map *)
         ]; (* Module *)
      (* Output *)
      Grid[
        If[dir === "Vertical",
           List@ gridArg[{cont}, {d*2, fix},"FrameLRResize",{split[#] - d, fix} &],
           (* else *)
           List /@ gridArg[{cont}, {fix, d*2},"FrameTBResize", {fix, split[#] - d} &]
        ],
        Spacings -> {0, -.1}]]];

SplitPane[val_, arg___] /; NumberQ[val] := 
   Module[{x = val}, SplitPane[Dynamic[x], arg]];
```

Here is how it may look:

```
SplitPane[{300, 300}, 
 {
   Manipulate[Plot[Sin[x (1 + a x)], {x, 0, 6}], {a, 0, 2}], 
   Factorial[123], 
   CompleteGraph[5]
 }, {900, 300}]
```

[image]

Can't comment of performance problems you mentioned. Also, when you start dragging with the mouse, the real cursor position is often quite off with respect to the divider position. This is both for your and my versions, perhaps some more precise scaling is needed.

Just want to emphasize once again - generalization became only possible after I did the refactoring, to separate the splitting logic from the visualization-related things. As to the optimization, I also think that it will be much easier to attempt optimizing this version than the original one, for the same reasons.

**EDIT**

I hesitated a bit to add this note, but it must be mentioned that my solution above, while working, shows one practice which is considered **bad** by expert UI mma programmers. Namely, it uses `Module`- generated variables inside `Dynamic` inner to that `Module` (in particular, `split` in the code above, also various auxiliary functions). The reasons I used it are that I wasn't able to make this work with only `DynamicModule`- generated variables, plus `Module`- generated variables always worked for me before. However, please see the post by John Fultz in [this](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/browse_thread/thread/5dc2cce710d1a871) MathGroup thread, where he states that this practice should be avoided.

Comment: @Sjoerd It did. But I am interested in the topic. Also, I am not a UI person, so sometimes I try to get a little more of that.

Comment: `Unevaluated /@ Unevaluated[{content}]` :)

Comment: @belisaruis What's so funny? It is one way to map `Unevaluated` on a list :) . Even though the content gets evaluated currently, I wrote most of the code such that it would support the unevaluated content, should we wish to impose some `Hold`-attributes on `SplitPane` (well, may be it is just an overkill).

Comment: @Leonid I know. It just sounds funny. Something like "Hey! I already told you not to touch this!" :)

Comment: @belisarius Indeed :) I did not think about it this way.

Comment: Nice work. By the way, the reason that the mouse position is off with respect to the divider position is because in `onMouseDraggedCode[n_]`, `temp` is the new position of divider `n` relative to the left-hand side (cq top) of the frame but `split[n]` stores the position of the divider relative to its direct neighbour. This means that `split[n]` should be set to something like `split[n]=temp-Sum[split[i],{i,n-1}]` instead.

Comment: @Heike Thanks, this is certainly a step in the right direction - I overlooked that. But this is a cure for an additional inconsistency I introduced with refactoring, while I rather meant an effect which is common for both original code and my solution, and which still does not go away. If you look closely, when you drag the mouse, the actual mouse position is different from where the divider currently is, and this difference varies depending on where you are in the pane. I'd prefer the mouse position to always stick to the space occupied by the divider, like it usually is in text editors.

Comment: Nice code Leonid, it gives me quite a bit of homework to understand. I don't want to seem greedy or dissatisfied, but when I talked about generalization to multiple panes, I actually thought about combining vertical *and* horizontal panes as well :) I'm working on understanding and expanding your solutions atm.

Comment: @Istvan You can easily combine vertical and horizontal panes by nesting say two horizontal panes inside one vertical and so on. As to my code, the piece related to `gridArg` is still pretty ugly, there should be a simpler way to do it. Anyways, thanks for the accept, and good luck.

Answer (score 6):

Heavily building on Leonid's solution, here is my version. I've applied several changes, basically to make it easier to track dynamic size-changes and because I simply failed to internalize part of Leonid's code.

Changes made:

- Removed `DividerWidth` option, now it cannot be set by user. It is not that important.
- Maximum horizontal size (`maxX` in the posts above) was dropped as it is now calculated from the user specified panel-width values: `w`.
- First argument (`w`, the main dynamic variable) saves the widths of panels explicitely instead of saving divider positions. Also, it was made to be a list (`w[[n]]`) instead of a function (as `split[n]` was in Leonid's version).
- Added minimize/restore buttons to dividers.
- Restricted divider movement: dividers can only be moved from their left to their right neigbour, no further movement is possible.
- Fine tuned divider width, `ImageMargins`, `FrameMargins`, `Spacings` to allow zero-sized panes.

Problems still to deal with:

- When minimizing/maximizing dividers, they should overlap left/rightmost ones. A LIFO stack of dividers would solve the problem of setting a divider to max, and than trying to change other dividers via their buttons. This might cause some problem, as they set back to previous states. The problem with stacking dividers is that it cannot be solved in Grid, or can only be solved with very specifically tuned negative Spacings. I think it does not worth dealing with.
- Minor alignment issues when shrinking a panel to zero width/height. This I can live with.

```
ClearAll[SplitPane];
Options[SplitPane] = {Direction -> "Vertical", Paneled -> True};
SplitPane[opts___?OptionQ] := 
  Module[{dummy = {200, 200}}, SplitPane[Dynamic[dummy], opts]];
SplitPane[val_, opts___?OptionQ] := SplitPane[val, {"", ""}, opts];
SplitPane[val_, content_, opts___?OptionQ] := 
  SplitPane[val, content, Automatic, opts];
SplitPane[Dynamic[w_], cont_, s_, opts___?OptionQ] :=
  DynamicModule[{
    scrollPane, divPane, onMouseDownCode, onMouseDraggedCode, grid,
    dir, panel, bg, coord, mouse, icon, sizeD, sizeB,
    num, old, pos, origo, temp, max, prev, state, fix},

   {dir, panel} = {Direction, Paneled} /. {opts} /. Options@SplitPane;
   dir = dir /. {Bottom | Top | "Vertical" -> "Vertical", _ -> 
       "Horizontal"};
   bg = panel /. {None | False -> GrayLevel@.9, _ -> None};
   panel = 
    panel /. {None | False -> 
       None, _ -> {RGBColor[0.70588, 0.70588, 0.70588]}}; (* 
   Simulate Panel-like colors on the frame. *)
   fix = s /. {Automatic -> If[dir === "Vertical", 300, 800]};

   (* {coordinate function, mouse cursor, button icon, divider size, 
   button size} *)
   {coord, mouse, icon, sizeD, sizeB} = Switch[dir,
     "Vertical", {First, 
      "FrameLRResize", {"\[RightPointer]", "\[LeftPointer]"}, {5, 
       fix}, {5, 60}},
     "Horizontal", {(max - Last@#) &, 
      "FrameTBResize", {"\[DownPointer]", "\[UpPointer]"}, {fix, 
       7}, {60, 7}}
     ];

   SetAttributes[{scrollPane, grid}, HoldAll];
   (* Framed is required below becase otherwise the horizontal \
version of scrollPane cannot be set to zero height. *)
   scrollPane[expr_, size_] := 
    Framed[Pane[expr, Scrollbars -> Automatic, 
      AppearanceElements -> None, ImageSizeAction -> "Scrollable", 
      ImageMargins -> 0, FrameMargins -> 0, ImageSize -> size], 
     FrameStyle -> panel, ImageMargins -> 0, FrameMargins -> 0, 
     ImageSize -> size];
   divPane[n_] :=
    Deploy@EventHandler[MouseAppearance[Framed[
        Item[Button[Dynamic@If[state[[n]], First@icon, Last@icon],

          If[state[[n]], prev[[n]] = w; 
           w[[n]] = max - Sum[w[[i]], {i, n - 1}]; 
           Do[w[[i]] = 0, {i, n + 1, num}]; state[[n]] = False;, 
           w = prev[[n]]; state[[n]] = True;]
          , ContentPadding -> False, ImageSize -> sizeB, 
          FrameMargins -> 0, ImageMargins -> -1, 
          Appearance -> "Palette"], Alignment -> {Center, Center}]
        , ImageSize -> sizeD, FrameStyle -> None, ImageMargins -> 0, 
        FrameMargins -> 0, Background -> bg], mouse], 
      "MouseDown" :> onMouseDownCode@n, 
      "MouseDragged" :> onMouseDraggedCode@n, PassEventsDown -> True];
   onMouseDownCode[n_] := (
     old = {w[[n]], w[[n + 1]]};
     origo = coord@MousePosition@"CellContentsAbsolute";
     );
   onMouseDraggedCode[n_] := (
     temp = coord@MousePosition@"CellContentsAbsolute" - origo;
     w[[n]] = Min[Max[0, First@old + temp], Total@old];
     w[[n + 1]] = Total@old - w[[n]];
     );
   (* Framed is required below because it gives the expression \
margins. Otherwise, 
   if the scrollPane is set with larger than 0 FrameMargins, 
   they cannot be shrinked to zero width. *)
   grid[content_, size_] := 
    Riffle[MapThread[
      Dynamic[scrollPane[Framed[#1, FrameStyle -> None], size@#2], 
        TrackedSymbols :> {w}] &, {content, Range@Length@w}], 
     Dynamic[divPane@#, TrackedSymbols :> {w}] & /@ 
      Range@((Length@w) - 1)];

   Deploy@Grid[If[dir === "Vertical",
      List@grid[cont, {w[[#]], fix} &],
      List /@ grid[cont, {fix, w[[#]]} &]
      ], Spacings -> {0, -.1}, 
     ItemSize -> {{Table[0, {Length@w}]}, {Table[0, {Length@w}]}}],

   Initialization :> (
     (* w = width data list for all panels *)
     (* m = number of panels *)
     (* state = button states *)
     (* prev = previous state of w *)
     (* max = total width of all panels *)
     num = Length@w; state = True & /@ Range@num; 
     prev = w & /@ Range@num; max = Total@w;)
   ];
SplitPane[val_, 
    arg___] /; (Head@val === List \[And] And @@ (NumberQ /@ val)) := 
  Module[{x = val}, SplitPane[Dynamic@x, arg]];
```

Let's try a vertically splitted pane:

```
w = {200, 50, 100, 300};
SplitPane[
 Dynamic@w, {Manipulate[Plot[Sin[x (1 + a x)], {x, 0, 6}], {a, 0, 2}],
   Null, CompleteGraph[5], "121234"}]
```

[image: vertical example]

Here is a horizontally splitted pane:

```
SplitPane[{50, 50, 50, 
  50}, {Manipulate[Plot[Sin[x (1 + a x)], {x, 0, 6}], {a, 0, 2}, 
   ContentSize -> 300], Null, CompleteGraph[5], "121234"}, 
 Direction -> "Horizontal"]
```

[image: horizontal example]

Vertical and horizontal panes combined:

```
xpane = {200, 300};
ypane = {200, 50};
SplitPane[Dynamic@xpane, {
  Manipulate[Plot[Sin[x (1 + a x)], {x, 0, 6}], {a, 0, 2}],
  Dynamic[
   SplitPane[Dynamic@ypane, {CompleteGraph[5], "status"}, Last@xpane, 
    Paneled -> False, Direction -> "Horizontal"], 
   TrackedSymbols :> {xpane}]
  }, 300, Direction -> "Vertical"]
```

[image: combined example]

I would like to hear your ideas/comments on this solution.